# InnoIDE Icon as parameter error

Tags: inno-setup

I need to ship my application with different icons, according to the client. In order to do so, I define a `MyIcon` parameter.

```
[Init]
#define Client "BigOne"
#if Client="BigOne"
#define MyIcon ".\img\bigone\program.ico"
#endif

[Setup]
SetupIconFile={#MyIcon}
;This does not work: the path cannot be found.
```

However, without the parameter definition, it works just fine:

```
[Setup]
SetupIconFile=".\img\bigone\program.ico"
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Inno Setup 5.5.4 (u). Also, I cannot see anything wrong in your code. Maybe there was an issue in preprocessor, hard to tell, but for me your code works just fine. Which version are you using btw. ?

Comment: I just upgraded to Inno Setup 5.5.4 (u) but nothing changed.

Comment: Well, so then we need to compare what's different on mine and your system. For my test I have stored script in this pseudo folder tree `C:\1\2\3\4\5\Script.iss`, where each number stands for one subfolder. The icon path then obviously was `C:\1\2\3\4\5\img\bigone\program.ico`. Could you show yours ?

Comment: I have the same here, except with more subfolders: C:\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\Script.iss and C:\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\img\bigone\programm.ico

Comment: Even that works fine for me. To be honest, I'm out of ideas. Could you put the following line at the end of your script (just change the file name) `#expr SaveToFile("C:\PreprocessedScript.iss")`. Then open the file specified in the argument and check what is stored there. The line does the only thing, it saves the preprocessed script, which will evaluate those constants into script. Then post the evaluated path from that preprocessed script into your question, if you can.

Comment: AARG, it was a typo! (of course :-) ) Your idea to put `#expr SaveToFile("C:\PreprocessedScript.iss")` was great. I wrote the invalid `{#MyIcon}` into my `DestDir` in order to see it. Worked great. Thanks a lot TLama!

Answer (score 0):

ISPP uses `==` for the comparison operator:

```
#if client == "bigone"
#define MyIcon ".\img\bigone\program.ico"
#elif client == "anotherone"
#define MyIcon ".\img\anotherone\program.ico"
#elif client == "someoneelse"
#define MyIcon ".\img\someonelse\program.ico"
#else
#define MyIcon ".\img\program.ico"
#endif
```

Alternatively, you may be able to use:

```
#define MyIcon ".\img\" + Client + "\program.ico"
```

Comment: Deanna, if the problem were in equal operator, the `MyIcon` variable won't be declared, and the preprocessor would raise `Undeclared identifier: "MyIcon"` error. Single equal operator was not a problem here.

Comment: There is here a very interesting issue. Writing `if Client="BigOne"` indeed did not work well. Following that first `if` was a second one: `if Client="BigTwo"`. And whatever what the `Client` was, the two `if` were entered... I was about to write a new question about this, but you solved it in advance! :-)

Comment: @Nicolas then from what you describe, `=` assigns, as with most other C like languages, further confusing things. If my answer helped you solve your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Deanna, your answer helped me, that is right, thanks a lot, but it does not provide the answer to my question. @TLama also greatly helped me, but without being able to answer my question  - of course: the problem was a typo in my actual code, not on the example I published. So sorry for both of you, I cannot mark your answers as accepted. :-(